# Regex to Match Quoted String Containing Escapes Quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match a double quoted string - with the possibility that an escaped double quote may reside inside this string.

My current attempt at this regular expression can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/mvfMoo/3):

```
^"([^"]|\\")*"
```

Where I am attempting to run this against the following value:

```
"sdfs\"dasf"
```

The regular expression will complete at the second double quote, not at the third one as intended. However, if I add an `$` at the end of the regular expression, it will correctly parse correctly. Unfortunately, I cannot use the end of string symbol (`$`) in my code implementation.

It seems that the capturing group is not greedy enough and allows the second double quote to go to the end of the regular expression.

Any ideas what would cause this behaviour or how to remedy this?

Comment: If the backslash is used in other context, thus before any other char than `"`, is it still used to escape or does it have to be treated literal then?

Comment: I would say the backslash is always used to escape the next character.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
"(?!\\").+"
```